# Customize the list of tcolorboxes appearance

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I have the following code to generate a "List of Examples" using the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, list inside=exam]{texample}[1][]{
    breakable,
    boxsep=0pt,
    leftrule=4pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
    colframe=gray!40,
    oversize,
    title={Example~\thetcbcounter},
    fonttitle=\normalfont\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    fontupper=\itshape,
    detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\hspace{0.5em}}
}

\begin{document}

\tcblistof[\section*]{exam}{Lista de Exemplos}
\pagebreak

\begin{texample}
    test
\end{texample}

\end{document}
```

Here is how the list looks after running this code:

[image]

However I want it to look similar to this:

[image]

So, I want the following:

- The "List of Examples" should be centered
- Each item in the list should be "Example   1 - title of example"

How can I do it?

Comment: Yes because my old post was closed I don't know why... I deleted the old post and clarify even more this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with (might not be the best solution though but it seems to work)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\tcbset{
    myexamplestyle/.style={
        boxsep=0pt,
        leftrule=4pt,
        rightrule=0pt,
        toprule=0pt,
        bottomrule=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        before skip=\topsep,
        after skip=\topsep,
        arc=0pt,
        outer arc=0pt,
        colback=white,
        colframe=gray!40,
        oversize,
        title={Example~\thetcbcounter},
        fonttitle=\normalfont\bfseries,
        coltitle=black,
        fontupper=\itshape,
        detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\hspace{0.5em}},
        separator sign={\ -}
    }
}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, list inside=exam]{myexample}{Example}{myexamplestyle}{}

\makeatletter 
    \renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \renewcommand\numberline[1]{Example #1 - }
    \tcblistof[\section*]{exam}{\centering Lista de Exemplos}
\endgroup

\begin{myexample}{Title of example}{}
    Example of an example
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}{Title of second example}{}
    Second example of an example
\end{myexample}


\end{document}
```

[image]

In this code, I've switched from using tcolorbox to tcbtheorem, which allows you to give the examples names. The code `\renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}` is there to fix some spacing issues in the list. The code `\renewcommand\numberline[1]{Example #1 - }` adds the labels to the front of each entry in the list.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this clever answer! Exactly what I wanted!